# Adding an opacity black screen to twitter post pop-up screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter

I would like to add an opacity black screen when the post twitter pop-up screen pops open. Here is my current code for opening the pop-up post screen which works just fine. All I simply want to do is add an opacity dark screen behind the pop-up and then have it either reload the page on closing the pop-up or remove the black screen after posting tweet to twitter.

**CODE:**

```
<script>
    $('.popup').click(function(event) {
        var width  = 575,
        height = 400,
        left   = ($(window).width()  - 575)  / 2,
        top    = ($(window).height() - 400) / 2,
        url    = this.href,
        opts   = 'status=1' +
            ',width='  + width  +
            ',height=' + height +
            ',top='    + top    +
            ',left='   + left;

        window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if youre using twitters web intents I guess you could use setinterval to check for the presence of something thats displayed / added to the dom of the popup AFTER a post is made (i.e. in the popup if AFTER posting to twitter it says "your post has been made" (for example) then you check the value of that dom element repeatedly (while the popup is open (probably a more elegant way to do this, admittedly) and when that value is present then you can gracefully hide the popup and the overlay using something like

```
$('#twitter, #overlay').fadeOut();
```

Comment: That's all fine, but I need the black overlay to hide when after you post to twitter from the pop twitter window.

Comment: what method of posting to twitter are you using in the popup? Twitters web intents or a 'custom' api v1.1 / oauth method?

Comment: Hi, thank you for a taking a look. If you view the screenshot below; http://cl.ly/image/1E3K0X1J3z10 that is what I'm using..All I simply want to do is to add a black opacity mask behind the pop-up twitter post and after you post hide the black opacity mask behind.